# Android : Take a photo from with in my layout without starting a camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera, crop

I want to take a photo from my camera, however I don't want to start a new intent to capture a photo but I want the camera to open inside my layout and then click a button to take the photo, like in the bellow picture.

[image]

So is it possible to do it because i didn't find any ressources about this, also I prefer that the token photo to be cropped?

Comment: make imageView become clickable will solve your problem ?

Comment: For custom camera view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543244/custom-camera-android.
For circle surfaceView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443911/creating-circle-in-surfaceview-on-button-click-android
Almost everything is already on StackOverflow. Just search for it.

Comment: You have to make costume camera  So that you can design your Surface view in your desire manner

Comment: @JohnJoe I'm sorry but I don't understand how making the imageView clickable will prevent opening the camera intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google demo of Camera2 Api. It will help you.
Link : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the camera runtime permission. You can then access the camera API directly.

This `SurfaceView` for example will show the preview image in your layout structure (from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)):

```
/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You get the `Camera` instance with this code:

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

And you display it in your `Activity` like this:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }
}
```

See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).